# A projective variety is irreducible if and only if it does not contain a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper closed subset of $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb C}$.  Is it true that $X$ is irreducible if and only if it does not contain a line $ax+by+cz = 0$?  I have never seen or thought about irreducibility this way.

This is claimed in these [notes](http://web.math.ku.dk/~kiming/lecture_notes/2005-2006-elliptic_curves/elliptic_curves-irreducibility-intersection_with_lines.pdf) on elliptic curves in the proof that an elliptic curve is irreducible.

Comment: For an elliptic curve (which in this case means a cubic) what you say is correct. The only non-trivial decomposition for 3 is $2+1$ or $1+1+1$. Higher degree curves, this is false.

Comment: You're saying if $X$ is a projective curve defined by a cubic equation, then the proper irreducible subsets of $X$ can either be lines or quadratics?

Comment: Oh I see..if $X = Z(f)$ and $X_0 = Z(f_0)$ is contained in $X$ for $f, f_0$ homogeneous, then $f_0$ divides $f$.